# Cannot retrieve image which has http in its url

Tags: asp.net, http, asp.net-core, https

guys, I'm new to asp.net core. I want to show some images on my site but the images are over the unsecured connection for example http://image.png . If I write this absolute link inside image tag asp.net make a request to HTTPS instead of HTTP thus returning 402 error. How can I solve this?

Comment: Make sure you have allowed the loading of static files.

Comment: Could you please share the details codes and the image url example for us to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's was, not a problem with asp.net core it was the problem with a package I installed to minify the code. The minification code was also removing https or HTTP in the absolute link.